# Mouse position on page load is throwing off jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cursor, mouseover

I have a small header that needs to come in from the top of the page, then fade and move to the right.

After it's faded and on the right, when a user mouses over the header, it should fade back in and move back left to display more information.

On the subsequent mouseout it goes back to the left and fades again.

Everything is working fine with this, except if the user has their mouse over the div when it initially comes on the page. If that's the case, the first jQuery event that is fired off is the mouseout event.  And the div is set 200px too far to the right. Basically moving it off the page entirely.

I'm trying to solve this with setTimeout but it's not working.

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#special_box').animate({top: '+=100'}, 300);
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#special_box').fadeTo('slow', .3).animate({right: '-=200'}, 300);
        }, 10000);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#special_box').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1).animate({right: '+=200'}, 300);
            });
            $('#special_box').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', .3).animate({right: '-=200'}, 300);
            });
        }, 12000);
    });
</script>
```

css:

```
.special_box    {z-index: 7;
            height: 30px;
            width: 400px; 
            position: fixed;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            top:-100px;
            right:0px;}
```

html:

```
<div class="special_box" id="special_box">
    Hello Cleveland!
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that you have not yet tried to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reliably wait for the initial animation to finish, you can specify it as a `.delay().animate().delay().fadeTo().animate().promise().then(fn)` chain, with attachment of the mouseover/mouseout handlers in the callback `fn`.

In full :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var $special_box = $('#special_box');
     $special_box.delay(2000).animate({top: '+=100'}, 300).delay(8000).fadeTo('slow', .3).animate({right: '-=200'}, 300).promise().then(function() {
        $special_box.mouseover(function() {
            $special_box.fadeTo('fast', 1).animate({right: '+=200'}, 300);
        });
        $special_box.mouseout(function(){
            $special_box.fadeTo('fast', .3).animate({right: '-=200'}, 300);
        });
    });
});
```

You might also like to consider :

- to ensure images are loaded before the initial animation occurs, wrap in `$(document).load(...)` instead of `$(document).ready(...)`
- to better cater for rapid mouse movements, include `.stop()` in both the mouseover/mouseout handlers
- for better behaviour, respond to mouseenter/mouseleave events instead of mouseover/mouseout

Comment: thanks for the help.  Indeed, mouseenter/mouseleave are providing much more of what we're going for.  And I'm reading about `.promise()`.  You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.delay()`. It delays the execution of functions.

See the full documentation [here.](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.example').slideUp(200).delay(1000).fadeIn(400);
});
```

Comment: Adding a delay on the mouseout event fixed it.  Thanks @Gorkurin.  I'll throw the solution up for future generations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes, then you could use the `.addClass()` method.

After the `div` is animated on load use `.addClass('yourClassName');` and make the `mouseover` and `mouseout` for the new class.

```
$('.yourClassName').on('mouseover',function(){
   // Your code here
});
```